# How to use bluetooth headset microphone with Windows 11 PC and have good quality playback sound and also recording mic sound?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, microphone

I have an issue with a Bluetooth headset. When the headset mic is enabled and OBS Studio is capturing its sound, I hear bad playback quality and low sound. For now, I solve this issue by disabling the headset mic and using the laptop's mic instead. Is there any possibility I could use a headset mic, capture headset mic's sound with OBS Studio (or another recording app) and also get good sound quality and loud enough sound? And I would like to know why this happen. I would say the biggest bottleneck would be Bluetooth data transmission bandwidth, but I understand where it could apply in this situation. Or maybe other issues causes this. Thanks.

Comment: In short, the only way to get high quality sound when using a headset + mic is to use a wired headset. Bluetooth just cannot cope with the bandwidth.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok, thank you, I just now understood how it really works. I thought that if "Handsfree telephony" setting is enabled, mic is being used every time, but it's actually only being used when some app uses it and only then the sound quality becomes worse.  Thanks for letting me now it's not possible.